# How does PHP5 'clone' work?

Tags: php, clone

Edit: This behaviour is reproducible with [query globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301766/mutability-and-reference-of-php5-get-variables) on.

I have the following:

```
  $_SESSION['query_key'] = $_GET['query_key'];
  print($query_key);
```

Vs.

```
  $_SESSION['query_key'] = clone $_GET['query_key'];
  print($query_key);
```

The former prints out the value of $query_key, while the latter prints nothing.
What sort of weird side effect is this of clone?

Answer (score 3):

You must be doing something very weird with your code.
[clone](http://www.php.net/clone) is for use on objects.  Unless you're stuffing objects into $_GET then that code will result in a fatal error (or a warning in older PHP versions).

@Michael Haren - clone actually does a shallow copy of an object, that is, it copies all the properties, but if a property is a reference to another object it will copy the reference, not clone the other object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301766/php5-get-variables for why I'm using clone, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really answer the question specifically, but based on your comment to Roborg I don't think this is a good solution for the problem you refer to in your other question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301766/php5-get-variables)) - you would be better off disabling register_globals

as soon as you do

```
$_SESSION['query_key'] = 'anything'
```

$query_key will be a reference to  `$_SESSION['query_key']`, so cloning what you are putting into it will make no difference

**Edit**

Cloning only works with objects, so you cannot clone a string. That will result in a fatal error. I think if you look in your logs or set display_errors to 'On' you will get an error rather than a blank page

Comment: Thanks tomaigh, disabling register_globals fixed it... your answer hasn't explained why it was blank after the clone however.. any idea?