# Mutability and Reference of PHP5 GET Variables

Tags: php, variables

I have the following in a page e.g. `/mypage?myvar=oldvalue`

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar'];
$myvar = 'a_new_string'
```

Now `$_SESSION['myvar']` has the value `'a_new_string'`

Is this by design?

How can I copy the *value* of `'myvar'` rather than a reference to it?

Comment: The title isn't really descriptive. Plus: where are you setting myvar? in the same script right after the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register_globals is the invention of the devil. Fortunately in PHP 6.0 it will be entirely disabled. It wasn't just a huge security problem, it makes people confuse. Please turn it off in your php.ini using
register_globals = Off
More information: https://www.php.net/register_globals
Also you can check the current settings with the command
if (ini_get(register_globals)) echo "turn it off! :)';

Comment: @EoghanM you could have solved it 2 hours earlier if you had read my answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, but dh2k used the phrase 'invention of the devil' which is how I feel about PHP right now :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature not a bug :-)

luckily you can turn it off, set [register_globals = off](http://www.php.net/register_globals) in your php.ini

Comment: I suppose it depends on the exact version .... In the page I linked there are numerous (user) warnings about register_globals such as "If you manipulate $user you'll manipulate $_SESSION['user'] as well" which I figured is what the OP is suffering from

Comment: This sure does sound like it's related to register globals. Are you sure that you have disabled it correctly? Edit the php.ini to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this with register_globals on and off and can't reproduce it.  What version of PHP are you using (I'm on 5.2.6).

Answer (score 0):

After running this:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_GET['myvar'] = ''; 
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $_GET['myvar']; 
$myvar = 'a_new_string'; 
var_dump($_SESSION); 
?>
```

on PHP 5.2.6 I get this:

```
array(1) { ["myvar"]=>  string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Sorry Moranar, I forgot to specify that I've got ?myvar=oldvalue in the query string, You are right that there is no change without myvar in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

$_Get['myvar'] is an array item $myvar is a variable.there is no relation between these two

($_GET is a superglobal array)

### consider the following example

$myarry=array('myvar'=>'myvalue');- here myvar is an item in the array variable $myarray
$myvar='';-here myvar itself be a variable.